# Graphs do not look the same on .exe as they are on Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, exe, pyinstaller

I have converted my project from `.py` file to `.exe` file.

On my project I produce some graphs, and they look very neat when I run the project through `Spyder`.
Unfortunately, when I convert it to .exe file, it doesn't.

Bellow is a picture of a graph from `Spyder`:
[image: Graph from Spyder]

And this is a picture of a graph produced via the `.exe` file:
[image: Graph from .exe]

And some graphs even look worse.With this graph I used the following code:

1. First I draw a graph based on my parameters:

   ```
   if (not self.ax):
      self.ax= self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.65])
   else:
      self.ax.set_position([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.65])
   if (self.ax2):
      self.fig.delaxes(self.ax2)
      self.ax2=None
   self.ax.cla()
   self.ax.scatter(volt_chk,cap_chk,label="Capacitance Chuck")
   self.ax.scatter(volt_rls,cap_rls,label="Capacitance Release")
   self.ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (v)')
   self.ax.set_ylabel('Capacitance')
   self.axParamText=self.ax.text(0.1, 0.9,'Vmax= '+str(Vmax)+'; Step1= '+str(Step1)+'; Step2= '+str(Step2)+'; Threshold= '+str(Threshold)+'; dt= '+str(dt)+'; maxCritVolt= '+str(maxCritVolt)+'; multiplier= '+str(multiplier),transform=self.fig.transFigure)
   self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()     
   self.ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.75), bbox_transform=self.ax.transAxes)
   ```
2. After that, I do some adjustments to include the test results you can see on the right side:

   ```
       if (not self.ax):
           self.ax= self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.65])
           self.ax.set_position([0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.65])
       if(self.skipped==True):
           self.ax.text(0.82, 0.6,'Test result: Skipped',transform=self.fig.transFigure)
       elif (self.stopped==True):
               self.axResText=self.ax.text(0.82, 0.6,'Test result: Stopped',transform=self.fig.transFigure)
       elif(self.passed=='Threshold'):
           self.axResText= self.ax.text(0.82, 0.6,'Test result: Failed\nDid not pass Threshold',transform=self.fig.transFigure)
       elif(self.passed==False):
           self.axResText= self.ax.text(0.82, 0.6,'Test result: Failed\nCritcal Voltage= '+str(critVolt)+'\nmaxCritVolt= '+str(maxCritVolt),transform=self.fig.transFigure)
       else:
           self.axResText= self.ax.text(0.82, 0.6,'Test result: Passed\nCritcal Voltage= '+str(critVolt)+'\nmaxCritVolt= '+str(maxCritVolt),transform=self.fig.transFigure)
   ```

I converted through `pyinstaller`.

What can I do regarding this? Is there something I can do or will I always have to go through trial and error until getting it right when covnerting `.py` to `.exe`?

Right now I see no solution other than changing all of the scales, convert, check, and do this back and forth until it's right - a thing that may take me a ton of time since it is a long code with a lot of graphs..

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT: Forgot to mention - this is only happening with the graphs, everything's fine with labels, buttons, etc.. Used these to create my graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
```

Comment: When the graphs are produced, Matplotlib uses different sets of defaults. Dump the defaults using `print(plt.rcParams, file=open('dumpSpyder','w'))` and `print(plt.rcParams, file=open('dumpExe,'w'))` and compare

Comment: I added both lines to my code but it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: All the details of the plot not explicitly set are controlled by the contents of  `plt.rcParams`.  Matplotlib may have, for different reasons, different versions of `plt.rcParams` — if the appearance of the same graph is different between Spyder and .exe, I'd suspect that there is a difference in `rc.Params`, hence I suggested to dump _to a file_, from Spyder, its content and dump, _to a different file_, its content from the .exe — so you have to use different prints in the two versions and beware that what you print is saved in files, not shown on screen.  Check differences and fix.

Comment: I have a couple of issues though: first, I import matploblib at one file, but I produce the graph on a different file (I basically send an instance of a figure), therefor I am not sure how to print it after the graphs are printed (because again I am not importing plt on this file). I produced two files at the beginning using the lines that you gave me but they seem to be the same. second, I didn't really understand HOW to change it, even if I found differences between them. Thanks again!